# Is it possible to change the network security group of a Azure VM via REST API?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-virtual-network

I don't even know how to change the network security group of an Azure VM via the portal... I hardly found anything useful from the official doc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create and manage NSGs, such as using Portal, Powershell, CLI and **REST API**.

More about how to manage the network security group of an Azure VM via **portal**, refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal).

More about how to configure the network security group of an Azure VM via **REST API**, refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networksecuritygroups).

Learn more about NSG, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Wayne. However, I've read the document many times even before I saw your reply, and I was never able to find the exact answer to my question which is "**CHANGE** the network security group of an Azure VM via the portal/REST API". Would you please pinpoint in the documents?

Comment: @truth_lover, these  two documents both show how to **"change"** the NSG. Due to Azure each NSG has priority, you can change add rules with to higher priority to change NSG. Also,in Azure portal you can just edit it.(Click the rule and edit it )

If you want to associate another NSG to the VM. you can click the NIC>Network security group>edit>Choose another exiting NSG>Save.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the virtual machine and select "Networking" from the "Settings" menu.
2. Click on the "Network Interface" associated to the VM.
3. In the "Settings" menu of the Network Interface, click on "Network Security Group".
4. Select the desired Network Security Group from the drop down menu and select "Save"

Note: VM should be shut down to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is possible

> if you have multiple VMs with single NIC all those will be impacted with this change

Steps are pretty simple

- Go to you VM
- Navigate to Networking from Left pane
- in the main panel you would see your associated NIC (Click on it)
- In the NIC window from left pane select "Network Security Group"
- From the drop down list select your Security group and then click on save button